# C# equivalent for pyModbus

Tags: c#, python, plc, pymodbus

I would like to develop a C# application to monitor a Sick PLC using modbus. I have an example program for talking to the PLC which is written in Python and uses the module pyModbus. Is there a C# nugget package that has the same functionality as pyModbus?

Comment: I had good experience with NModbus.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Nuget package, but instead a full Visual Studio solution. AdvancedHMI includes a Modbus driver and also has lots of tools that will connect to the driver data without having to write code.

www.advancedhmi.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for but you can try *libmodbus* which is written in C and use it in your project:

[How to create a DLL in C and use it in your C# project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w)

Or since you're already familiar with *pyModbus*, maybe you can try to make it work with IronPython and call it from C#:

[Dynamic Language Integration in a C# World](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/dynamic-language-integration-in-a-c-world/)